# Re-align axis on plot using python and matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have created a basic heat map in python using the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# FILE INPUT PATH
FILE_PATH_INPUT = 'C:/Python/'

# IMPORT FILE
flights_raw = pd.read_excel(FILE_PATH_INPUT+'flights.xlsx', sheetname='flights')
flights_raw["month"] = pd.Categorical(flights_raw["month"], flights_raw.month.unique())
flights_raw.head()

# CREATE MATRIX
flight_matrix = flights_raw.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
flight_matrix

fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(12,12))
heatplot = ax.imshow(flight_matrix, cmap='binary')
ax.set_xticklabels(flight_matrix.columns, rotation = 90)
ax.set_yticklabels(flight_matrix.index)

tick_spacing = 1
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
ax.set_title("Variance of Delivery Days By Period")
ax.set_xlabel('DAYS LATE (-EARLY)')
ax.set_ylabel('PERIOD')
```

Which results in the below plot.

[image]

However my axis labels seem to be in the wrong place.

My Y Axis should all be dropped down a space, and my horizontal axis should all be shifted to the right, the data should span from 1 - 14, not 2-14.

I have tried changing the tick spacing but this just stretches out the positioning, I am thinking i may need to offset the positioning of the labels ?

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never set the ticklabels without setting the ticks as well. What this essentially does is keeping an `AutoLocator` for the axes but using a `FixedFormatter` for the labels.

So when using a `FixedFormatter` as is done with `set_xticklabels` always make sure to also use a `FixedLocator`, e.g. using `set_xticks`.

```
ax.set_xticks(list(range(len(labels))))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Of course after setting the formatter and locator this way, you should not set them to something different later. So the following two lines need to be deleted from the code.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, i'm still new to python, how does this fit in with my code, do i need to define 'labels' ?

Comment: `labels` are the labels you want to put on the axes.

Comment: i used ax.set_xticks(list(range(len(flight_matrix.columns))))
ax.set_xticklabels(flight_matrix.columns) but still get the same output

Comment: Sorry, I thought that that it was obvious, but I updated the answer. Please note that you should always provide a [mcve] such that people can test their answer.

Comment: seems obvious now, thanks for your time and effort, will try and construct a better question next time